# Recursive List Function

Tags: php, mysql, object

I have a list of objects which are parents of other same objects with "n" child.

In order to list the parents, I've managed to do so with this:

```
echo "<ol>";
            foreach ($indicator_dimensions as $dimension) {
                if (empty($dimension->parent)) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo $dimension->dimension;
                    $subdimensions = Indicator_dimension::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM indicator_dimension where parent=".$dimension->id);
                    if (count($subdimensions) != 0) {
                        find_leaves($subdimensions);
                    }
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            }
            echo "</ol>";
```

To list their children, I'm using this function:

```
function find_leaves($dimensions){
                echo "<ol>";
                foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo $dimension->dimension;
                        if (!empty($dimension->parent)) {
                            $subdimensions = Indicator_dimension::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM indicator_dimension where parent=".$dimension->id);
                            if (count($subdimensions) != 0) {
                                find_leaves($subdimensions);
                            }
                        }
                    echo "</li>";
                }
                echo "</ol>";
            }
```

Although it's working, it's ugly code I'd like to refactor but ain't got the brains yet...

Appreciate in advance any tips of enhancement!

Comment: first you should read about more efficient techniques to store and retrieve tree data in relational databases like [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) or [closure tables](http://karwin.blogspot.de/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you need a classic tree implementation. It consists of nodes having n child nodes.
I wrote a little example implementation [**here**](http://ideone.com/DxUZ2T).I know the traversal isn't done very clean but it serves your needs.

I delegated all the magic to the ListRenderer's traverse-method. This digs recursivley into the children of the currently traversed node:

```
protected function traverse(Node $node) {
    if($node->__toString()) $this->output .= '<li>'.$node.'</li>';  //echo current node
    if($node->hasChildren()) {
        $this->output .= '<ol>';
        foreach($node->getChildren() as $child) {
            $this->traverse($child);                                //repeat for children
        }
        $this->output .= '</ol>';
    }
}
```

Please note that the root node does not echo `<li>root</li>` because its label is empty. So the resulting output of the example would be:

```
<ol>
    <li>sub1</li>
    <li>sub2</li>
    <ol>
        <li>sub a</li>
        <li>sub b</li>
        <li>sub c</li>
    </ol>
    <li>sub3</li>
</ol>
```

Which is exactly what you want.

---

If you want to learn more about tree traversal, take a look at [the wikipedia article about tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).